# Fredhopper is not indexing sucessfully published DCPs

Tags: smarttarget

Fredhopper is not indexing my successfully published DCPs. In the publishing queue the DCP shows status "Success", and the deployer does not mention any errors.

In the Fredhopper XML loader log in ...fredhopper/data/instances/indexer/log/xmlloader.log I do see an issue though.

```
2014-09-22 16:35:06,753 INFO  [XML-Parser-Thread] DirectoryContentProvider.java:373 50104 File `/home/fredhopper/fredhopper/data/instances/indexer/data/xml/incoming/batch/tcm_0-2321-66560_component.xml' is polled from directory content provider `batch -> batch'
2014-09-22 16:35:06,782 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] CategoryNameHandler.java:82 10602 Category identifier `tcm_0_1_1' in item operation with id `tcm_1-55-16_tcm_1-52-32' contains '_'. Consider removing this, as FAS uses this symbol as a delimiter internally do represent the category path to root. || fredhopper@istdevapp:fredhopper/data/installations/FAS tags/fas/fas-7.5.0.16/engine@107262
2014-09-22 16:35:06,783 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] CategoryNameHandler.java:82 10602 Category identifier `tcm_1_1_2' in item operation with id `tcm_1-55-16_tcm_1-52-32' contains '_'. Consider removing this, as FAS uses this symbol as a delimiter internally do represent the category path to root. || fredhopper@istdevapp:fredhopper/data/installations/FAS tags/fas/fas-7.5.0.16/engine@107262
2014-09-22 16:35:06,783 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] CategoryNameHandler.java:82 10602 Category identifier `tcm_1_6_2' in item operation with id `tcm_1-55-16_tcm_1-52-32' contains '_'. Consider removing this, as FAS uses this symbol as a delimiter internally do represent the category path to root. || fredhopper@istdevapp:fredhopper/data/installations/FAS tags/fas/fas-7.5.0.16/engine@107262
2014-09-22 16:35:06,799 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] AttributeValueHandler.java:164 50223 Neither content nor identifier provided for attribute `tcm_1_47_8_title' of item `tcm_1-55-16_tcm_1-52-32' || fredhopper@istdevapp:fredhopper/data/installations/FAS tags/fas/fas-7.5.0.16/engine@107262
2014-09-22 16:35:06,799 ERROR [XML-Parser-Thread] FredhopperHandler.java:354 10499 Rejecting faulty item `tcm_1-55-16_tcm_1-52-32'. || fredhopper@istdevapp:fredhopper/data/installations/FAS tags/fas/fas-7.5.0.16/engine@107262
2014-09-22 16:35:06,805 INFO  [XML-Parser-Thread] DirectoryContentProvider.java:756 We have successfully moved processed file tcm_0-2321-66560_component.xml to /home/fredhopper/fredhopper/data/instances/indexer/data/xml/processed/batch/20140922-143506805-tcm_0-2321-66560_component.xml
2014-09-22 16:35:06,827 INFO  [xmlloader] FASItemsIndexWriter.java:430 50105 Parsed batch id `maximum batch size "4000"'. Details: '1 operations , skipped: 1()'
2014-09-22 16:35:06,827 PROGRESS [xmlloader] FASItemsIndexWriter.java:432 10541 itemstore.size = '0' items.
2014-09-22 16:35:06,828 PROGRESS [xmlloader] FASItemsIndexWriter.java:437 100010 Batch completed, itemstore lastTransactionId '18', itemstore itemCount '0', operations performed: 'add: 0, delete: 0, replace: 0, update: 0, skip: 1'.
2014-09-22 16:35:06,828 INFO  [xmlloader] LeaderFollowersIndexCoordinationPolicy.java:153 Performing progress check from previous: 0 to new batch 18...
2014-09-22 16:35:07,016 INFO  [xmlloader] LeaderFollowersIndexCoordinationPolicy.java:171 Follower "NAVIGATION.catalog01" reports progress '18', coordinator expectation '0'.
2014-09-22 16:35:07,017 INFO  [xmlloader] LeaderFollowersIndexCoordinationPolicy.java:192 Checking index contributor: "NAVIGATION.catalog01", at transaction: "18"
2014-09-22 16:35:07,017 INFO  [xmlloader] XmlLoaderApp.java:419 50108 There are no XML files in the incoming dirs. `0' items were successfully added to the item store till now.  Waiting for input...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning message gives a hint: `Neither content nor identifier provided for attribute 'tcm_1_47_8_title' of item 'tcm_1-55-16_tcm_1-52-32'`. This means the Tridion component tcm:1-55-16 has no value for the required field 'Title' in schema tcm:1-47-8. Apparently this component is out of sync with the schema has no value for a field which is required in the schema.

The error says that it is rejecting this specific item, if there would be other items in the same publish transaction those could still be processed successfully.