# Indexing components in Fredhopper

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

I'm facing a similar issue to the one mentioned [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7934/fredhopper-is-not-indexing-sucessfully-published-dcps) by Jan, basically FredHopper doesn't seem to be indexing fields for a couple of DCPs I'm successfully publishing and using in SmartTarget. I'm using these components successfully in both promotions and experiments, and I'm able to find them in Fredhopper by searching their item ids, so they're certainly in Fredhopper and have been indexed at one point. What I'm trying to do now is index a specific field in this component for use in a search implementation. To do this I've followed the [docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-CBA6D89F-81DF-4745-A9C1-D71EDED81BC2) here, but I'm still unable to search based on the contents of this field. Checking the logs Jan mentions in his answer, I see:

```
2016-04-29 14:42:19,310 INFO  [XML-Parser-Thread] DirectoryContentProvider.java:373 50104 File `C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\SmartTarget\data\xml\incoming\batch\tcm_0-10248-66560_component.xml' is polled from directory content provider `batch -> batch'
2016-04-29 14:42:19,340 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] CategoryNameHandler.java:82 10602 Category identifier `tcm_0_3_1' in item operation with id `tcm_3-3420-16_tcm_3-3419-32' contains '_'. Consider removing this, as FAS uses this symbol as a delimiter internally do represent the category path to root. || JohnW@WIN-SQC3BSLTNDP:C:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
2016-04-29 14:42:19,340 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] CategoryNameHandler.java:82 10602 Category identifier `tcm_3_1_2' in item operation with id `tcm_3-3420-16_tcm_3-3419-32' contains '_'. Consider removing this, as FAS uses this symbol as a delimiter internally do represent the category path to root. || JohnW@WIN-SQC3BSLTNDP:C:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
2016-04-29 14:42:19,340 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] CategoryNameHandler.java:82 10602 Category identifier `tcm_3_46_2' in item operation with id `tcm_3-3420-16_tcm_3-3419-32' contains '_'. Consider removing this, as FAS uses this symbol as a delimiter internally do represent the category path to root. || JohnW@WIN-SQC3BSLTNDP:C:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
2016-04-29 14:42:19,340 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] CategoryNameHandler.java:82 10602 Category identifier `tcm_3_63_2' in item operation with id `tcm_3-3420-16_tcm_3-3419-32' contains '_'. Consider removing this, as FAS uses this symbol as a delimiter internally do represent the category path to root. || JohnW@WIN-SQC3BSLTNDP:C:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
2016-04-29 14:42:19,344 INFO  [XML-Parser-Thread] DirectoryContentProvider.java:756 We have successfully moved processed file tcm_0-10248-66560_component.xml to C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\SmartTarget\data\xml\processed\batch\20160429-154219343-tcm_0-10248-66560_component.xml
2016-04-29 14:42:19,352 INFO  [XML-Parser-Thread] DirectoryContentProvider.java:373 50104 File `C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\SmartTarget\data\xml\incoming\batch\tcm_0-10249-66560_component.xml' is polled from directory content provider `batch -> batch'
2016-04-29 14:42:19,354 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] CategoryNameHandler.java:82 10602 Category identifier `tcm_0_3_1' in item operation with id `tcm_3-3421-16_tcm_3-3419-32' contains '_'. Consider removing this, as FAS uses this symbol as a delimiter internally do represent the category path to root. || JohnW@WIN-SQC3BSLTNDP:C:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
2016-04-29 14:42:19,354 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] CategoryNameHandler.java:82 10602 Category identifier `tcm_3_1_2' in item operation with id `tcm_3-3421-16_tcm_3-3419-32' contains '_'. Consider removing this, as FAS uses this symbol as a delimiter internally do represent the category path to root. || JohnW@WIN-SQC3BSLTNDP:C:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
2016-04-29 14:42:19,355 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] CategoryNameHandler.java:82 10602 Category identifier `tcm_3_46_2' in item operation with id `tcm_3-3421-16_tcm_3-3419-32' contains '_'. Consider removing this, as FAS uses this symbol as a delimiter internally do represent the category path to root. || JohnW@WIN-SQC3BSLTNDP:C:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
2016-04-29 14:42:19,397 WARN  [XML-Parser-Thread] CategoryNameHandler.java:82 10602 Category identifier `tcm_3_63_2' in item operation with id `tcm_3-3421-16_tcm_3-3419-32' contains '_'. Consider removing this, as FAS uses this symbol as a delimiter internally do represent the category path to root. || JohnW@WIN-SQC3BSLTNDP:C:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
2016-04-29 14:42:19,404 INFO  [XML-Parser-Thread] DirectoryContentProvider.java:756 We have successfully moved processed file tcm_0-10249-66560_component.xml to C:\fredhopper\bin\..\data\instances\SmartTarget\data\xml\processed\batch\20160429-154219404-tcm_0-10249-66560_component.xml
2016-04-29 14:42:19,517 INFO  [xmlloader] FASItemsIndexWriter.java:430 50105 Parsed batch id `maximum batch size "4000"'. Details: '2 operations , skipped: 2()'
2016-04-29 14:42:19,517 PROGRESS [xmlloader] FASItemsIndexWriter.java:432 10541 itemstore.size = '35' items.
```

The item operation IDs mentioned in the warn messages correspond to the components I'm trying to index, but Jan seems to have the same warnings with no issues. I also notice that 2 operations are being skipped, which I suspect, but can't confirm, are the indexing operations for the two components I'm working with. There doesn't seem to be any additional information about why these operations are being skipped in any logs I've been able to find.

Has anyone seen a situation where certain operations are skipped during a Fredhopper indexing, or are there logs that might give me more of a clue?

Answer (score 2):

Likely the "skipped" operations are indeed your items, and the skipping might be because of the ID issue -- the warning is really meant to be serious :)

You might be able to get more information out of the xmlloader by increasing the logging level: modify `C:\fredhopper\data\instances\SmartTarget\config\log4j.xml`. This configuration is only used for this instance, if it doesn't exist FAS will use the configuration file from the installation directory.

Please check the documentation for how to modify the logging level though.